# Custom breaks and labels are missing on date axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a scatterplot, made using ggplot, with dates on the x-axis (covering 8 weeks) and random points.  I want a vertical line in the middle at a test date, and markers every 2 weeks (forward and back).  Below is a minimum working example.

I have specified breaks and labels as per http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-axis-ticks-a-guide-to-customize-tick-marks-and-labels.

But they do not appear...

```
Test = '2010-05-02'
data = data.frame(x=-28:28)
data$date = as.Date(Test)+data$x
data$y = sample(1:6, size=57, replace=TRUE)

ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(date, y, color=y), alpha=0.45, size=1.2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=as.Date(Test), color = '#0B50EF', linetype='twodash', size = 0.70) +
  theme_bw(7) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +  
  xlab('') +
  ylab('') +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(as.Date(Test)-28,as.Date(Test)-14,as.Date(Test),as.Date(Test)+14,as.Date(Test)+28), 
                   labels=c(as.Date(Test)-28,as.Date(Test)-14,as.Date(Test),as.Date(Test)+14,as.Date(Test)+28))
```

Comment: generally, I'd recommend against using `xlab/ylab = ' '` because you are *actually* plotting an empty space. Use `NULL` instead. As for your other problem, you may want to have a look at `?scale_x_date`

Comment: OK.  Thank you.  I will change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into problems using dates. They are not really continuous nor discrete. So neither `scale_x_continous` nor `scale_x_discrete` will work like a charm. 
The challenge is the conversion between character and date class. 
In my example, I am keeping everything as `Date`, from the very beginning creating "Test" as Date class. In order to make your code a bit clearer, I created the break vector beforehand, using `seq`. There are certainly more elegany ways out there. I've also removed all your redundant code which is not pertinent to the question.

```r
library(tidyverse)

Test = as.Date('2010-05-02') #makes your life easier
data = data.frame(x=-28:28)
data$date = Test + data$x
data$y = sample(1:6, size=57, replace=TRUE)

my_breaks <- c(seq(Test-28,'2 weeks', to =Test), 
               seq(Test,'2 weeks', to =  Test + 28))

ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(date, y)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.Date(Test)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = my_breaks)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it.

Comment: Anyone new coming to this, you can format the date labels like this:  scale_x_date(breaks=myBreaks, labels= date_format('%d %b %Y'))